# Pytest: How can I mock the return value of child function when calling the parent function in pytest unit test function

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

`preocess_video` in `workflow.py` calls `detect_objects()` whose return_value is what I want to mock.
But When I call `process_video()` in `test_workflow.py` I don't get the mocked return value, instead It actually call the `detect_objects` function.

How can I mock the return value of `detect_objects` when calling the parent function `process_video`

#### Directory Structure

```bash
.
├── __tests__
│   └── test_workflow.py
└── video_processor
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── detectors
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── object.py
    └── workflow.py
```

#### Workflow.py

```py
def process_video(request: Request, config: Config):
    object_detections = detect_objects(request, config) # Want to mock the return value of detect_objects
    # Detect_objects call other function internally
    # More logic
    # Some more logic
    return data
```

#### test_workfkow.py

```py
object_detections_dict == ... # sample data
def test_process_workflow(requests_mock, mocker):
    # Arrange
    request = Request(...)
    config = Config(...)
    
    # Mock some API calls
    requests_mock.post(...)
    requests_mock.post(...)
    
    with mocker.patch("video_processor.detectors.object.detect_objects") as mock:
         mock.return_value = object_detection_dict
         process_video(request, config)
```

Tried this as suggested in comments:

```py
# test_workflow.py
object_detections_dict == ... # sample data dict

@pytest.fixture
def detect_objects_fixture(mocker: MockerFixture):
    mocker.patch("video_processor.detectors.object.detect_objects", return_value = object_detection_dict)

def test_process_workflow(requests_mock, detect_objects_fixture):
    # Arrange
    request = Request(...)
    config = Config(...)
    
    # Mock some API calls
    requests_mock.post(...)
    requests_mock.post(...)
    

    result = process_video(request, config)
```

Comment: I added the complete exemple in my answer. This should work. Feel free to comment again if you need any hint.

Answer (score 0):

### Creating a fixture using pytest_mock and unitest.mock to patch the return value of a function

---

### Exemple :

```
@pytest.fixture
def detect_objects_fixture(mocker):
    mocker.patch("path to the detect objects function", return_value = whatever you want)
```

Add detect_objects_fixture to the parameters of your test function, pytest should use the fixture to patch the return value of the function you targeted.

Here is an example :

```
import pytest
import unittest.mock
import pytest_mock.plugin



def process_video():
    object_detections = detect_objects()
    # Detect_objects call other function internally
    # More logic
    # Some more logic
    return object_detections

def detect_objects():
    return [1,2]

@pytest.fixture
def detect_objects_fixture(mocker):
    return mocker.patch("modulewhereitis.detect_objects", return_value=[3])

def test_process_video(detect_objects_fixture):
    assert process_video() == [3]
```

Output :

```
PASSED                                        [100%]
```

### Documentation

- [Pytest-mock](https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) : `pip install pytest-mock`
- [Unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)
- [Pytest fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/fixtures.html)

Comment: Hi Loïc! I tried it (Updated the post with code). But it still runs the detect object function...and return a different value(which comes by actually running the function) instead of the mocked return value

Comment: How do you launch your test ? Do you start all the tests, or do you start on THIS test ? Have you tried making a test config and running your tests from there ?

Comment: I edited my answer with a complete exemple. It works on my side.